# React native flat list don't show data screen after generating APK

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

I'm using react-native, and everything was working well while I was developing, but, when I built the APK (using this tutorial: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content) and installed it on my device, 
the flat list don't show any data 
everything is working well the login screen connect to api the loged in
so the api work well 
so why the flatlist don't show any data 
. Did anybody had the same issue?

[image]

[image]

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getCoffeeCategory()
  }

//flatlist code
    <FlatList
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
          horizontal={true}
          data={this.props.data}
          renderItem={this._renderListItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}

        />
```

Comment: Please can you post your Flatlist code ?

Comment: @KishanBharda ok i add the code